# BST, is it possible to find next lowest in O(lg N)?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

The `TreeNode` class  is defined with only left and right child.

```
public class TreeNode {

    public int val;
    public TreeNode left, right;

    public TreeNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

My code finds the next lowest node in O(n). I was wondering if it's possible to find it in lg(N) given that the node doesn't have a pointer to its parent node.

```
// run time O(n)
    public static Integer findNextLowest(TreeNode root, int target) {
        Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
        TreeNode cur = root;

        while (cur != null || stack.size() > 0) {

            while (cur != null) {
                stack.push(cur);
                cur = cur.right;
            }
            TreeNode node = stack.pop();
            if (node.val < target) return node.val; // found the next lowest
            cur = node.left;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static TreeNode findNextLowest(TreeNode root, int target){
    TreeNode node = root;
    TreeNode res = null;
    while(node != null){
        while(node != null && node.val >= target){
            node = node.left;
        }
        while(node != null && node.val < target){
            res = node;
            node = node.right;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but I don't think it works. If you use this tree here https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Binary_search_tree.svg/200px-Binary_search_tree.svg.png and use the target value `9`. Your code returns null;

Comment: Hi Tony, if the target value is     9, the code enters loop "while(node.val < target)" and res is marked as 8. So it will return 8.

Comment: did you run it with the tree I mentioned? To make it easier for you: 

TreeNode root = new TreeNode(8);
        root.left = new TreeNode(3);
        root.right = new TreeNode(10);

        root.left.left = new TreeNode(1);
        root.left.right = new TreeNode(6);
        root.left.right.left = new TreeNode(4);
        root.left.right.right = new TreeNode(7);

        root.right.right = new TreeNode(14);
        root.right.left = new TreeNode(13);

Comment: Hi Tony, you are right! make an improvement. It works now. :]

Answer (score 0):

No, because you haven't implemented a **B**inary **S**earch **T**ree, just a Binary Tree.

A BST will constrain its values such that `left.val` < `val` < `right.val`, so you can do

```
// run time O(log(n)) if cur is balanced
public static Integer findNextLowest(TreeNode cur, int target) {        
    if (target < cur.val) { return cur.left != null ? findNextLowest(cur.left, target) : null; }
    if (curr.right != null)
    { 
        Integer result = findNextLowest(cur.right, target);
        if (result != null) { return result; }
    }
    return cur.val;
}
```

You should use something like a [R-B tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) to ensure it is balanced

Comment: Your code is wrong, because with this BST https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Binary_search_tree.svg/200px-Binary_search_tree.svg.png , and I tell you the root node `8` and the target number `9` (not exists on the tree). Your code returns null, but the next lowest should be `8`. - duh!

Comment: Why don't you test it before you say my code does not work? My code is an inorder traversal from the largest number to the smallest. It is guaranteed to be 100% correct.

Comment: The main point is that you can't be log(N) with a total traversal, you need to have the tree depth balanced. I was adapting "find" to "lower bound"

Comment: the question never mentions that the BST is complete/balanced, so you cant make that assumption

Comment: In that case, the answer is simply "No, and you still don't have a BST"

Comment: Just consider the provided TreeNode `root` to be the root node of a BST, you don't need to define a BST class anyway.